# Get cell value using named range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing my first Excel VBA project and am having some trouble.
I'd like to get the value in a cell in the CurrentBalance column.  I'll be using ActiveCell.Row to get the row number.  And I'd like to use a named range for the column in case I need to insert additional columns later.

So what I'd like to have is:
BalanceVariable = "CurrentBalance"$ActiveCell.Row

I've been trying things for an hour and can't get it to work.  I've tried Range and Cell and othe things.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CurrentBalance is a named range.

```
Sub test()
Dim BalanceVariable As Double
BalanceVariable = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("CurrentBalance").Column)
MsgBox "the current balance is " & BalanceVariable

End Sub
```

[image]